# swift : Can't set variable in imagePickerController result

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

In my class, after I have saved the picked image, i'm trying to set a variable value, but it doesn't change.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    let imageName = Util.generateFilename(activityId.integerValue)
    var localPath = Util.getExpensePath(activityId.stringValue)
    localPath = localPath?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageName, isDirectory: false)

    let image = Util.reduceImageSize(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage, compressionQuality: 0.5)
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    data!.writeToFile(localPath!.path!, atomically: true)

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imagePickedPath = localPath!.path!
}

@IBAction func viewButtonClick(sender: UIButton)
{
     showImage(imagePickedPath!)
}
```

Debugging, imagePickedPath seems to change value after execution of last line in first method but when i click to view button, imagePickedPath continue to has the old value. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting the variable before dismissing the picker?

Comment: I tried it, nothing change

Comment: Try and set a property observer on your imagePickerPath property. Add a break point to it so we can see if it changes value in between picking an image and clicking the view button.

Comment: Ok @JustJasper, thanks to your hint i figured out when it happen : after dismiss picker, value was changed to the old one. I resolved adding:

picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            self.imagePickedPath = localPath!.path!
        })
but to be true, i didn't understand why it happens. Someone can explain this?

Comment: Your welcome :) Glad I could help

Comment: It seems that some piece of code was changing the variable after you set it to the correct value. Or maybe your run hadn't run yet, do you run stuff in the background thread? It's hard to say without seeing more code. The code you added is guaranteed to ran after all code is finished since you put it in a completion handler. This guarantees that the variable is set to the required value and thus shows up correctly when you click the button.